# Spring Event with @EventListener and void method

Tags: java, spring, events, listener, observer-pattern

I searched for a while but have no clue what I am missing.

I want to implement the observer pattern in Spring, to update documents in MongoDB which will create a notification in the front-end.

I implemented a Service class for the notifications (here are more than one, I show you just two of them), using @EventListener annotation

```
    @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class NotificationService {
    
    @EventListener ({ContextStartedEvent.class})
    public void updateNotificationForIdea(String ideaId) {

    //some logic inside the Service classes

        }
    }

    @EventListener ({ContextStartedEvent.class})
    public void createNotificationForNewComment(String ideaId, String creatorId) {
        
    //some logic inside the Service classes

        }
}
```

and I tried to implement the service, from where I want to send the notification

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CommentService {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public CommentServiceResult createComment(Comment comment, String creatorId) {

        // some logic

eventPublisher.publishEvent(); //here is where I miss something

        return CommentServiceResult.builder()
                .comment(createdComment)
                .resultState(state)
                .build();
    }
```

I read that I need something like an "EventHelperClass" and tried to build this:

```
public class NotificationEvents extends  ApplicationEvent{

    public NotificationEvents(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
    
    private void updateNotificationForIdea(String ideaId){
        
    }

    private void createNotificationForNewComment(String ideaId, String creatorId) {
        
    }
}
```

but I really don't know how to get the notifications from the NotificationsService in here (because they are void and are not a simple String message), to start the event from within CommentService...

I shortened the dependencies from the services and removed the internal logik for readability...

Answer (score 0):

```
eventPublisher.publishEvent(...)
```

fires an event, you'll need to pass an event object as parameter, e.g.

```
public class CustomSpringEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private String message;

    public CustomSpringEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Methods annotated with `@EventListener ({CustomSpringEvent.class})` will catch it.

In your case:

CommentService fires an CommentEvent (fields: Comment comment, String creatorId).

Any Bean with a method

```
@EventListener ({CommentEvent.class})
void onCommentEvent(CommentEvent event) {
// ....
}
```

will catch it and get the event data.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Comment: I tried it out (the baeldung link I read before yet). Are you sure about the EventListener and the CommentEvent.class? Shouldn't it be the NotificationEvents.class? And how do I fire one specific event of the many events of my NotificationsService?

Comment: it's just a sample, name it as you like

Comment: `eventPublisher.publishEvent(new YourEvent(....))` fires a specific event